# Solving $f''(x)+f(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of $f''(x)+f(x)=0$

I know it has to be some sort of linear combination of cosine, sine or the exponential, but I was wondering if there was a general form for the solution before applying the initial conditions.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you find the solutions of the characteristic equation?

Comment: What is a characteristic equation?

Comment: I've not taken a formal course in ODEs so I might be fuzzy with terminology.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus)

Comment: @vadim: To clarify, it is just a linear combination of the solutions of the ODE?

Comment: The characteristic equation is a tool used to find solutions to a linear homogeneous  differential (or difference) equation with constant coefficients, such as you have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a second-order linear homogeneous differential equation of the type:

$$ af''(x)+bf'(x)+cf(x)=0. $$

The associated characteristic equation is

$$ ar^2+br+c =0. $$

Denote the roots of this equation by $r_1$ and $r_2$.

---

**If $r_1$ and $r_2$ are different and real**

The general solution is

$$f(x) = C_1 e^{r_1 x} +C_2 e^{r_2 x} $$

where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants to be determined.

---

**If $r_1=r_2=r$ is real**

The general solution is

$$f(x) = C_1 e^{r x} +C_2 xe^{r x}. $$

---

**If $r_1$ and $r_2$ are complex**

Suppose that $r_1=\alpha + \beta i$ and $r_2=\alpha - \beta i$. Then the general solution is

$$f(x) = e^{\alpha x}\left(C_1 \cos{\beta x} +C_2 \sin{\beta x} \right)$$

---

**Applying it to your example**

In your example $a=1$, $b=0$, and $c=1$ and the roots are complex: $r_1=i$ and $r_2=-i$. Hence, $\alpha=0$, $\beta=1$, and the general solution is

$$f(x) = C_1 \cos{ x} +C_2 \sin{ x} .$$

Comment: The roots of the characteristic equation are $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: @Element118 True. I'll fix it.

Comment: So in my example, the characteristic equation is $m^2+m=0\implies m(m+1)=0\implies m=0 \text{ or } m=-1?$ and so my $f(x)=\alpha e^{0\cdot x}+\beta e^{-x}=\alpha+\beta e^{-x}$?

Comment: @mzp Still wrong. There's no $e^x$ factor

Comment: @Dylan You are correct Sir. I fixed it.

Comment: @Crime The characteristic equation is $r^2+1=0 \Rightarrow r^2=-1$, which leads to the roots described in the answer.

Comment: Ah, ok: So if I understand correctly, because the characteristic equation yields complex roots $\pm i$,, this means that my roots are $r_1=\alpha+\beta i$ and $r_2=\alpha-\beta i$, where in this particular example, $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=1$, so $f(x)=A\cos x+ B\sin x$

Comment: @Crime Correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll definitely have to look up the proofs for the above cases later.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know what the characteristic equation is. If you have the two solutions of the characteristic, say $m_1$ and $m_2$, then a general solution to the ODE will be $$f(x)=Ae^{m_1x}+Be^{m_2x},$$ for constants 
$A$ and $B$.

EDIT: The characteristic equation of a second order linear homogeneous ODE $ay''+by'+cy=0$ is the equation $am^2+bm+c=0$. I think you can fill in the details.

Comment: So for example, in my example, the characteristic equation is $m^2+m=0\implies m(m+1)=0\implies m=0 \text{ or } m=-1?$ and so my $f(x)=\alpha e^{0\cdot x}+\beta e^{-x}=\alpha+\beta e^{-x}$?

Comment: Why would the solutions be real? Isn't the solution to the equation $m^2+1=0\implies m=\pm i?$

Comment: You are right, my bad.